# Possible to round edges of an image in kivy?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, kivy, edges

I had a question about my code and couldn't find any answers so I came here. Does anyone know if it is possible to round the edges of an image in kivy and how? I am not referring to rounding a button's edges.

My image code:

```
    Image:
        source: 'assets/images/banner/purple.jpeg'
        keep_ratio: True
        height: 250
        width: 350
        center_x: root.width / 2
        center_y: 575
```

P.S. Tried using the border property. No errors but no change in the image either :(

Answer (score 0):

In this case the best solution would be to do a canvas with a Ellipse:

kivy doc:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__canvas__circle__py.html

.kv

```
canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Ellipse:
            pos: 100, 100
            size: 200, 200
            source: 'assets/images/banner/purple.jpeg'
            angle_start: 0
            angle_end: 360
```

I would suggest also looking at

Dynamic Classes:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html

import, set and include :
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html

this would help you keep your main kv file as small as possible. And also so you have variables for example text colors and stuff so you only need to change in one place.

Hope it helps